# aws_dlm_lifecycle_policy's retain_rule - can you mix retain rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, lifecycle, snapshot

Is it possible to include both `count` and `interval` (with the corresponding `interval_unit`) conditions in the `aws_dlm_lifecycle_policy.policy_details.schedule.**retain_rule**` within the *single* schedule policy?

What I'd like to achieve is to specify a backup policy to keep N last EBS snapshots but at the same time discards any of them that are older than a certain threshold.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "dlm_assume_role" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["dlm.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "dlm_lifecycle_role" {
  name               = "dlm-lifecycle-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.dlm_assume_role.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "dlm_lifecycle" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    actions = [
      "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
      "ec2:CreateSnapshots",
      "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
      "ec2:DescribeInstances",
      "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
      "ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
    ]

    resources = ["*"]
  }

  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["ec2:CreateTags"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "dlm_lifecycle" {
  name   = "dlm-lifecycle-policy"
  role   = aws_iam_role.dlm_lifecycle_role.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.dlm_lifecycle.json
}

resource "aws_dlm_lifecycle_policy" "ebs_snapshot" {
  description        = "EC2 EBS DLM lifecycle policy"
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.dlm_lifecycle_role.arn
  state              = "ENABLED"

  policy_details {
    resource_types = ["VOLUME"]

    schedule {
      name = "${var.name_prefix} EC2 EBS backup policy"

      create_rule {
        interval      = var.ebs_snapshot_interval
        interval_unit = "HOURS"
      }

      retain_rule {
        interval      = var.ebs_snapshot_max_retain_period
        interval_unit = "DAYS"
        #### <<<< insert `count` here (?)
      }

      copy_tags = true
    }

    target_tags = {
      Name = "${var.name_prefix}"
    }
  }
}
```

On one hand, according to the [Terraform resource docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dlm_lifecycle_policy) these two parameters are not exclusive towards each other but on the other, it seems to be impossible to recreate such configuration in the AWS Web Console.

Comment: Please show a complete TF code demonstrating your issue and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: So what is the issue with setting `count` to a value of 14 for example? The link from your question is for the cross-region copying though. Is that what you want?

Comment: @MarkoE Very good question indeed!
The provisioning, example of which I showed above, is generally ephemeral, so to speak.

The mechanism I indented to implement was to relatively effortlessly ensure that these EBS Snapshots (state of which is NOT managed by the Terraform) are cleaned-up (e.g. after few years) once the infra has been tear-down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: It seems that currently it's not possible.

If someone intended to use `...schedule.retain_rule` and specify the COUNT along the `...schedule.deprecate_rule` (period threshold) then unfortunately it wouldn't work either - there's a bug in the resource documentation ([link to the issue on GH](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/27786))